# Matrix transformations of 3d shapes that are coplanar

Tags: matrices, transformation, plane-geometry

I am just attempting this question and I am bit confused by how I could find it. Could you help please?

transformation A is represented by

A= \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & x & 2\\\
7-x & -6 & 1\\\
5 & -5x & 2x
\end{bmatrix}

The tetrahedron H has vertices at O,P, Q, R.

O', P', Q', R' are the images of O, P, Q, R under transformation A.

Find the values of x for which O', P', Q', R' are coplanar

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: What have you tried? Attempted towards solving the question?

Comment: yes I have looked at it

Comment: "I have looked at it" is not showing us what you have tried. You can click "edit" below your question to add some details of what you've tried. Or you can skip that step, and your question will probably get closed. It's really up to you.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) and edit your question accordingly if you’d like to prevent it from being closed and actually get an answer. Here’s a hint, however: Are the vertices of $H$ coplanar? What does that mean for the rank of $A$?